# Wordpress Plugin | New Menu Page visible for new user role but not for WP-Administrator

Tags: wordpress, plugins, dashboard

I am creating a new `wordpress` plugin.
For this plugin I have created a new role named `mypluginadmin`.
The Plugin has a "new admin menu" page which is created with function

```
add_menu_page( string $page_title, string $menu_title, string $capability, string $menu_slug, callable $function = '', string $icon_url = '', int $position = null )
```

My problem is that by default a user can only have one `role` assigned.
When I have a user with this new `role` he can see the new page.
A user with the default `administrator` role can not see the new page but of cause he should.

What can I do that this new page is also visible for users with `administrator` role?

The parameter `$capability` of function `add_menu_page` is not an array where I could transmit more than one value.

Can anyone please help me?

Many thanks

Comment: i know that there are plugins which can assign more then one user role to a user, but that is not what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define ( add ) same `capability` for `administrator` and  `mypluginadmin` roles
and call that as value of `$capability` in `add_menu_page` function.

For example)

First add same capability with custom name for example "access_custom_admin_menu" to both user roles

```
// get the the role object
$admin_role = get_role( 'administrator' );
// grant the access_admin_custom_menu capability
$admin_role->add_cap( 'access_custom_admin_menu', true );

// get the the role object
$mypluginadmin_role = get_role( 'mypluginadmin' );
// grant the access_admin_custom_menu capability
$mypluginadmin_role ->add_cap( 'access_custom_admin_menu', true );
```

Then use that in function

```
add_menu_page( 'your_page_title', 'your_menu_title', 'access_custom_admin_menu', 'your_menu_slug', ....
```

In fact, the goal is to use a `capability` that only these two roles have and the other user roles do not have this `capability` , If you currently have the `capability` with this feature, you do not need to do the above and just use it

Comment: Thank you! - I will try and give you short feedback here! Many thanks for your fast and detailed feedback jiali! :)

Comment: @Pherox65 I hope it helps you find the solution

Comment: hey @jiali - many thanks for your help! your perfect detailed answer had solved my problem! Now everything works fine and i can see the new page with both user roles! Again, many thanks for your fast support :)!